# Как переименовать любой коммит в git?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rebase

Хочу переименовать десяток коммитов, но что-то не могу разобраться, как это сделать. Вот, к примеру, статья [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/201922/), но у меня загвоздка после `git rebase --interactive`, то есть редактор открывается такой же, но а дальше куда и что писать? Если пытаюсь написать что-то, то у меня почему-то пишет в самом низу и по одному символу. Делал я это на windows через терминал в SourceTree. Может, есть какой-то другой способ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git rebase --interactive` вам покажет в текстовом редакторе своего рода план: список коммитов и действий, которые к ним будут применены. По умолчанию всем коммитам сопоставлено действие `pick` - сохранить как есть. Ваша первая задача отредактировать действия на свой вкус. Доступные действия описаны в комментарии, отбитом символом `#`.

```
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
```

Вас в первую очередь интересует команда `r reword` - изменить текст сообщения. Не знаю, как SourceTree, а обычный шелл из пакета `msysgit` (мы ведь о Windows говорим?) предлагает в качестве редактора православный `vim`. Если у вас так же, и вы с ним не знакомы - смело давите кнопку `i` на клавиатуре и `vim` перейдет в режим редактирования. У нужных коммитов замените `pick` на `reword`. Теперь надо вернуться в командный режим, нажав `Esc`. Сохраняемся и выходим - набирайте на клавиатуре `:wq`, жмите `Enter`.

Редактор закроется, и `git` приступит к выполнению вашего плана. Для каждого коммита, помеченного действием `reword`, он откроет вам редактор и предложит отредактировать сообщение. Опять-таки, если у вас `vim` - жмем `i`, редактируем, `Esc`, сохраняем `:wq`.
На комментарий под текстом коммита, отбитый решеткой, не обращайте внимания. Он просто подсказывает вам, что делать, и в текст сообщения не попадет.

Comment: После того как сделал так, то у меня появилась отдельная ветка фиолетовая, то ли это не ветка, не знаю, вообщем я нажал слияние и получилось, что коммиты дублировались, и есть 2 старые коммита со старыми названиями и 2 с новыми. А выглядит это так ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/eJdIXbO.png

Comment: [Так, 14 год, да] если вы уже отправили данные на сервер, то ничего изменить не получится. Вернее, есть способ с аккуратным удалением репозитория на сервере без удаления на клиенте, но это, конечно, та еще пляска с бубном. Да еще можно историю PR и issues потерять (ну то есть PR в любом случае теряются, а issues можно выгрузить иногда).