# Как отредактировать заголовок последнего коммита?

Tags: git, git-commit

Написал неправильное сообщение, когда сделал `commit`, но ещё не сделал `push`. Как исправить?

Comment: Вероятно, стоит отметить один правильных ответов как решение. :)

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос про любой коммит: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/359475/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B2-git

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Вы можете дать новый заголовок

```
git commit --amend -m "ваш заголовок"
```

или

```
git commit --amend -c HEAD
```

если хотите отредактировать старый

Answer (score 3):

В похожем вопросе было очень интересное замечание, если вам нужно отредактировать коммит более старый, а не последний, используйте rebase interactive (например тут если искомый коммит 3мя ранее):

`git rebase -i HEAD~3`

Пометьте нужный коммит как `edit`, а потом делайте

`git commit --amend`

А после окончания редактирования коммита сделайте

`git rebase --continue`

чтобы завершить rebase.
Ну и как написал @Daniil следует потом сделать push force если коммиты уже в удаленном репозитории.

Answer (score 2):

```
git commit --amend -m "исправленный текст"
```

Если исправленный текст должен быть больше одной строки, то:

```
git commit --amend
```

Откроется текстовый редактор, и вы сможете внести исправления.