# Как изменить название снимка слияния (merge) в GIT?

Tags: git, git-merge

Через PhpStorm этого сделать нельзя, `reword` неактивен.

---

### Дополнение

- Этот снимок слияния не последний.
- Выделен тот снимок, который нужно переименовать.
  Его номер для примеров 0081534.

  [image: Место снимка в истории для rebase]
- После `git rebase -ip 0081534~1`. Новое имя снимка `Creating of version 0.1.0. ----`.

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/414158/178576

Comment: Добавьте ключ `-p` в вашем случае, иначе история "выпрямится". Теперь должно получиться. `git rebase -ip 0081534~1`

Comment: Сделал, но теперь вместо переименования у меня ещё ответвления появились.
  
И ещё, я думал изменяемые снимки будут от того, который переименовываю, но процесс пошёл по всей истории. Делаю всё в копии репозитория., так что возможности  пробовать не ограничены.

Comment: `Сделал, но теперь вместо переименования у меня ещё ответвления появились.` Это нормально. Нужно везде оставить pick, и только в том, что переименовываете - `r`. Я проверил на своем репо, после rebase останется точно такая же структура ветвления, но измененный коммит будет с другим хешем. `И ещё, я думал изменяемые снимки будут от того, который переименовываю`. Нет, rebase переписывает всю историю от указанной точки. У него такой алгоритм. Вы же можете вообще коммит поменять, вот git и проверяет, нет ли конфликтов. Сделайте `git log --oneline --decorate --graph` до и после и убедитесь.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `git rebase`. Желательно ознакомиться о работе с этой командой [заранее](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8), чтобы при возникновении внештатных ситуаций было понимание.

### 1. Найти SHA (хеш) "снимка слияния в GIT"

`git log --oneline --decorate --graph`, или используя GUI (`PhpStorm`).

Допустим, SHA равен `c9f100f51bcad0a1555f038ba0cc18b963d414f8`, git понимает и более короткую запись из первых символов (если совпадение только одно): `c9f100f`.

### 2. Делаем `git rebase`

`git rebase -ip c9f100f~1` - так перезаписываем историю + 1 коммит (как раз этот снимок).

**Следует добавить опцию `-p`** (вместе с интерактивностью `-i` получится `-ip`), чтобы rebase при перезаписи не сделал линейную структуру и оставил ветвление. В этом случае также можно исправить сообщение мержа.

Появится что-то типа этого:

```
pick c9f100f название коммита 2
pick b88027b название коммита 3
```

Теперь слово `pick` следует исправить на `r` или `reword`, даже подсказка внизу есть: `r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message`.

Получится так:

```
r c9f100f название коммита 2
pick b88027b название коммита 3
```

Теперь сохраняемся (`Ctrl + X`, `Y`, `Enter`) - если открылся nano (в конфиге гита стоит опция, какой редактор использовать, [см тут](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git)).

### 3. Редактируем сообщение коммита

Снова откроется редактор. С этим сложностей не должно быть. Сохраняем новое название коммита.

В конце git выведет: `Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.`. Проверяем: `git log`

Comment: Если это последний коммит в серии, то вместо всех эти сложностей достаточно `git commit --amend`

Comment: Делаю `git rebase -i 008153426403d8d3fb77367cdacecd8480b2c202~1`, вываливает все снимки, в которых не могу найти нужный.

Comment: `git show 008153426403d8d3fb77367cdacecd8480b2c202` - это тот коммит, который нужно исправить?

Comment: Да, это этот снимок.

Comment: @LazyBadger, я не утверждаю обратного. [И rebase может изменить мерж](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/). @andreikorzhyts он должен быть первым. Почему вы его не можете найти, это странно. Слияние в том же репозитории, с чем работаете, или в удаленном репозитории? Покажите `git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short` - ту часть, где `00815342640`.

Comment: @Total Pusher, по вашему формату не выводятся все ветки, поэтому добавил картинку с полной ситуацией.